# Unable to deploy app engine app using Eclipse plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My user has "App Engine Deployer" & "App Engine Admin" permission. When I try to deploy the app using Eclipse, I get following error -

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/index/add?app_id=xxxxxxxxxx&version=9&
403 Forbidden
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~xxxxxxxxxx').
```

Though when I check cloud control panel, I see that the app is deployed. Why this error?

Here is full deployment console detail:

```
Preparing to deploy:
Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\punit\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2201895061249198461.tmp'
Scanning for jsp files.
Compiling jsp files.
Scanning files on local disk.
Initiating update.
Cloning 3 static files.
Cloning 29 application files.

Deploying:
Uploading 0 files.
Initializing precompilation...
Deploying new version.
Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
Uploading index definitions.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/index/add?app_id=xxxxxxxxxx&version=9&
```

403 Forbidden
    You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~xxxxxxxxxx').

And here is stacktrace in the log:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/index/add?app_id=xxxxxxxxxx&version=9&
```

403 Forbidden
    You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~xxxxxxxxxx').

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:336)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:287)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:266)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.NoLoggingClientDeploySender.send(NoLoggingClientDeploySender.java:35)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1168)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.updateIndexes(AppVersionUpload.java:534)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:205)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:572)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:58)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: What is the result when deploying your app using [appcfg.cmd](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#using_appcfg_alternative) from the command line? You might try clicking on the 'Google' icon on the bottom right of the Eclipse UI and re-authorizing the plugin.

Comment: I didn't try appcfg.cmd but I tried re-authorizing the plugin which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It could very well be an actual permissions issue, and checking appcfg.cmd would help to determine if this is the case or if it is related to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error, no matter if I tried from Eclipse, from commandline with `mvn appengine:update` or with `appcfg.sh update`. The situation is that it's not possible to update

- Datastore indices
- Task queues
- Cron jobs

> 403 Forbidden You do not have permission to modify this app
>   (app_id=u's~xxxxxxxxxx').

The only way to achieve a complete deployment seems to grant the user *Project Owner* permissions (maybe *Project Editor* would have been enough, I didn't test that) at least temporarily.

Comment: I had the same trouble - I ended up creating a key for the "App Engine default service account", which seemed less of a security risk. :-/

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by adding Datastore Index Admin role. (Note: you would need to regenerate the key file if you are using a service account.)